# Rofi on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, i3-wm

I was sure this was going to be asked somewhere but I haven't found it... So there we go...

I want to use Rofi because it looks like it's more configurable than dmenu, and I want my stuff to look nice.

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with i3.

However - typing in terminal "rofi" doesn't suggest me any packages, and `sudo apt-get install rofi` doesn't find any package. I googled around in the package lists online - no luck.

Is there maybe a custom PPA or something where it can be found? Maybe I need to build it from source? Maybe it isn't compatible at all?

**TL;DR**: Rofi not found in package lists, how to install on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the deb package for 15.10 will also work on 14.04. You can download it here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rofi

Scroll down to where you see "The Wily Werewolf (supported)", click the arrow just below it to bring up the list of builds, and then download the correct .deb for you architecture (for me this is rofi_0.15.7-1_amd64.deb).

Then install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i rofi_0.15.7-1_amd64.deb
```

NOTE: run this command inside the directory to which you have downloaded the .deb file, and ensure the file name is correct depending on the file that you have downloaded.

You can use dpkg with the -r option to remove the package:

```
sudo dpkg -r rofi_0.15.7-1_amd64.deb
```

Source and further information: https://tuxdiary.com/2015/10/26/rofi/

Comment: How did you know the `.deb` package for 15.10 will work? Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: Could you also add the command to uninstall  it?

Comment: Working for Xenial 16.04 LTS as of December 2017. As it's part of _Universe_ `sudo apt-get install rofi` will work as well.